# Convert 1 zip file into multiple via SSH

Tags: ssh, ftp, zip

i have 1 zip file in my FTP with 10GB

i must convert it into multiple zip files, for example 10 zip files with 1GB each.

how can i do this via SSH?

thx =)

Comment: windows, linux, unix or??

Comment: If you just want to split it, there is already `split` command.

Comment: it is linux... =)

could you show me how to use it Billiska?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the man page of `zipsplit` which is usually installed along with `zip`.

```
zipsplit -n size zipfile
```

in your case

```
zipsplit -n 1073741824 zipfile
```